# Shell In A Box - Session closed when trying to login

Tags: ssh, localhost, html

I am trying to use Shell In A Box which implements a web server that can export arbitrary command line tools to a web based terminal emulator. This emulator is accessible to any JavaScript and CSS enabled web browser and does not require any additional browser plugins.

I am going through [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox) to implement it.

When I run the `shellinaboxd` executable in terminal using

```
shellinaboxd --port 4201
```

and open the `https://127.0.0.1:4201/` I get asked for login.

But when I type my name and hit enter I see Session Closed.

My `/etc/default/shellinabox` file looks like below :

```
# Should shellinaboxd start automatically
SHELLINABOX_DAEMON_START=1

# TCP port that shellinboxd's webserver listens on
SHELLINABOX_PORT=4200

# Parameters that are managed by the system and usually should not need
# changing:
# SHELLINABOX_DATADIR=/var/lib/shellinabox
# SHELLINABOX_USER=shellinabox
# SHELLINABOX_GROUP=shellinabox

# Any optional arguments (e.g. extra service definitions).  Make sure
# that that argument is quoted.
# SHELLINABOX_ARGS="--o-beep"
SHELLINABOX_ARGS="--disable-ssl-menu --service=/:LOGIN --no-beep --linkify=none --css=/etc/shellinabox/termstyle.css"
```

I tried the following too but it did not work:

1. https://github.com/iptq/shellinabox/issues/142
2. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57724

My `/etc/hosts` file is as below:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   abhishek-Latitude-3480


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

If anyone have used `shellinabox` or can guide me with its usage will be a big help.

Comment: Do the logs give any hints what happened in the moment the connection is dropped/closed? (i.e. `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/syslog` and if shellinabox has an own log this one too)

Comment: Also I wonder why you not use the version within the repositories.

Comment: @Videonauth I installed openssh-server and allowed port in iptables using 
 " sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT " and it worked. do not know how but can you shed any light on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/default/shellinabox` file using:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/shellinabox
```

and change the last line as:

```
--service=/:SSH:{remote_host}:{SSH_port}
```

Problem is solved!!!